# How to turn XAML to pure C#?

Tags: c#, xaml

How to turn XAML to pure C# (xaml was made for c# app )?

Comment: @Ole Jak: I can't say I see the need as to *why* you would do this, given all the benefits you get because of XAML.

Comment: In .NET Micro, you cannot use XAML. All of your WPF code has to be in C#.

Comment: Jonathan Allen +1... But btw there are some libs that work lot like XAML

Comment: Your question is not clear. Otherwise the answer is... write c# instead ? Instead of having a .xaml and a .xaml.cs associated, only use a .cs and build your UI inside.
I've thought about moving to pure C# a lot of time since I built some Flutter app.
More performance, less useless control in the tree (ex : if a control shouldn't be displayed, you don't add it with a visibility and converter which will trigger binding and all. Instead, you simply don't add it), fewer converter etc. Actually except maintenance and productivity, there is more benefit to use C# only.